# Standard CSS trick of before pseudo class not solving content disappearing under page header

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code in my main style file. Everywhere I've looked online says to use the ::before pseudo class to set the height and - margin to the same as the header.  I have done this, but whenever I click a link in the header that sends the user to the section div with the correct id, the content is still displayed behind the header.  Please help, as this is most frustrating!

```
header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #636;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #636 0%, #303 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #636), color-stop(1, #303));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #636 0%, #303 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 400;
}
content {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 340px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
}
section {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px 20px 0px 20px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
    section::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        margin: -50px 0 0;
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
section-content {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #636;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #303 0%, #636 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #303), color-stop(1, #636));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #303 0%, #636 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e4ebfd;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/links.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/particles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/team.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ticker.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xhr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles-config.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a name="#top" />
    <header>
        <a href="#about" class="nav">About</a>
        <a href="#roadmap" class="nav">Roadmap</a>
    </header>
    <ticker-wrapper>
        <ticker>
            <ticker-item>
                Current Era: 0
            </ticker-item>
            <ticker-item>
                Block Height: <script>document.getElementById('BLOCK_HEIGHT').innerHTML = coinData.BLOCK_HEIGHT</script>
            </ticker-item>
            <ticker-item>
                Total EGEM Supply: <script>document.getElementById('TOTAL_EGEM_SUPPLY').innerHTML = coinData.TOTAL_EGEM_SUPPLY</script>
            </ticker-item>
            <ticker-item>
                Market Cap (USD): $<script>document.getElementById('MARKET_CAP_USD').innerHTML = coinData.MARKET_CAP_USD</script>
            </ticker-item>
            <ticker-item>
                Average Exchange Price (USD): $<script>document.getElementById('AVERAGEUSD').innerHTML = coinData.AVERAGEUSD</script>
            </ticker-item>
        </ticker>
    </ticker-wrapper>
    <social class="social-media">
        <a href="http://discord.egem.io" alt="Discord" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons/discord-32.png" alt="Discord" class="social-anim" /></a>
        <!--<img src="images/social-icons/facebook-32.png"  alt="Facebook" class="social-anim" />-->
        <a href="https://t.me/EGEM_Team" alt="Telegram" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons/telegram-32.png" alt="Telegram" class="social-anim" /></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/EtherGemCoin" alt="Twitter" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons/twitter-32.png" alt="Twitter" class="social-anim" /></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH4uEyf5roU6ydButXYdiBg" alt="YouTube" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-icons/youtube-32.png" alt="YouTube" class="social-anim" /></a>
    </social>
    <particles-wrapper>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
    </particles-wrapper>
    <intro>
        <img src="images/logo.png" style="display: none; margin-top: 20px;" class="egem-logo" alt="EtherGem Logo" />
    </intro>
    <content>
        <section id="about">
            About EGEM
            <arrow class="scrollTop">
                &#9650;
            </arrow>
        </section>
        <section-content>
            <p>
                EGEM is the stable, pure, no pre-mine coin with applied technologies peernet and per block endowment.
            </p>
            <p>
                What does that really mean, though?
            </p>
            <p>
                EtherGem, "EGEM," is first and foremost, a pure community coin with no pre-mine. True to its roots as a cryptocurrency, the Proof of Work mining
                community will always be a part of EGEM's future and is the foundation of the EGEM launch. There is no ICO on EGEM and EGEM is its own primary
                blockchain, not just a token or concept on another chain. The EtherGem blockchain is an Ethereum network, meaning it starts with the tested and proven
                Ethereum (as in ETH) core technologies and builds from there. Technically, EGEM is an Ethereum chain as described in the yellow paper, with EIP150,
                EIP155, EIP158 applied from block 0. Block Rewards have 7 eras of reduction, including a dev reward enabled after block 5000. Developers and Community
                Managers are bound by a continuity agreement to maintain the network, community, and coin. There is no cap to EGEM at the moment. A monetary cap will be
                put in place when the community determines that the logical progression would be to cap the coin.
            </p>
            <p>
                An "applied technologies peernet" is where the EtherGem blockchain grows on a mineable token sidechain. Dual mining ethergem and a token is something
                new. The EGEM sidechain is designed to be very much an integral part of ongoing mainchain development, where peers can implement new technology
                while continuing to rely on a solid foundation. The sidechain and token will be available shortly after the mainnet release.
            </p>
            <p>
                View the EtherGem <a href="https://egem.io/roadmap.html" target="_new">white paper</a>.
            </p>
        </section-content>
        <section id="roadmap">
            Project Roadmap
            <arrow class="scrollTop">
                &#9650;
            </arrow>
        </section>
        <section-content class="aligncenter">
            <img src="images/roadmap.png" style="height: auto; width: 100%" />
        </section-content>
    </content>
    <footer>
        &copy;2018 The EtherGem Project, All Rights Reserved.
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML so we can see the issue you're having? It's hard to tell looking at just the CSS.

Comment: You have lots of unnecessary css declarations. Also, you dont want your content to be displayed under your header, but your header is fixed, so with that z-index set to 400, and no z-index specified for other positioned elements, it will always stay on top.

Comment: The header is supposed to be fixed and always display on top, hence position:fixed and the z-index.  What I want, is the section IDs to stop before they scroll under the header and have a 40px margin under that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using `::before` to solve this issue, but you can use height and negative margins.

I think what might be causing the issue in your example is that you're using the actual "title" element as your anchor element. I'd suggest making a separate (invisible) element your anchor element to make sure the it doesn't interfere with the normal layout of your page, and then style your "title" element however you want:

```css
/* important styles */
#demo {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section-anchor {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* styles for demo */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
header a {
  color: #fff;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.title {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(200,0,0,0.3);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #dff, #dff 10px, #eee 10px, #eee 20px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
p {
  height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid #bbb;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #ddd, #ddd 30px, #eee 30px, #eee 60px);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<header>
  <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</header>
<div class="section">
  <a class="section-anchor" name="section1"></a>
  <div class="title">Section 1</div>
  <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <a class="section-anchor" name="section2">-</a>
  <div class="title">Section 2</div>
  <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <a class="section-anchor" name="section3"></a>
  <div class="title">Section 3</div>
  <p>Text...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give this a go this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the header position to both relative and absolute, and see if either fixed it.

Comment: Neither of those will keep the header at the top of the page as the content scrolls.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what you meant. You need a sticky header!! https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `body{ padding-top: 50px; }`

Comment: Adding the same value(as of the header height) of padding to the body element, will set the header covering the unused top content of the body

Comment: Adding padding-top to the body just moves the page content down, but the section titles still disappear under the header when the link is clicked.

Comment: add html, body { height:100%; } and body{ min-height:100%}. This should fix the moving of the content

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap up everything below the header in a `main` section and displace it somewhat to the bottom.

The following CSS should help:

```
main {
  top: 2em; /* Modify to suit your needs */
  }
```

The problem: Since you mark the header's position as fixed, you are taking it out of the normal flow of elements so everything outside of your header fills the page as normal, with your header overlaying everything. To avoid this, you should displace everything else further down.